# Is codepipeline with jenkins a good solution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, aws-codepipeline

Pipelines costed 1$ per pipeline if we use any pipeline after a month when it was created, and we have 400-500 api endpoints and we have to create pipeline for every one of them,Is codepipeline with jenkins a good solution? [As shown here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hz2QJ420LPE&ab_channel=SandipDas)

Comment: Good solution for what? You have to provide much more details. What do you want to do? What's wrong with regular CP? What is your specific use-case that you would require Jenkins?

Comment: Cost is main issue 1$ per pipeline so 500$ for pipeline

Comment: Why does every api endpoint have a separate pipeline?

Comment: Every Micro service have separate pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you already using Jenkins? Based on the link you shared, keep in mind that you are paying for the EC2 instance that is running the Jenkins server

if you are starting fresh, you could use [CodeBuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/welcome.html) as a build server, it will offer a better cost long-term, because you pay only when CodeBuild is running

related to the [pricing of the CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/pricing/),

AWS CodePipeline costs $1.00 per active pipeline per month:

> An active pipeline is a pipeline that has existed for more than 30 days and has at least one code change that runs through it during the month. There is no charge for pipelines that have no new code changes running through them during the month. An active pipeline is not prorated for partial months.

If you are not using your pipeline, you are not paying

Comment: I am using CodeBuild. Can I use Jenkins instead of codepipeline So it will not cost that much.

Comment: of course, you don't need CodePipeline or CodeBuild at all, do everything in Jenkins running on an EC2 instance... the trade off is that you need to manage the Jenkins server